# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda

I'm trying to send data to a MySQL database hosted on AWS' RDS using a Lambda function. However, when I try to import the mysql module with `import mysql.connector` I get a "Runtime.ImportModuleError" error.

I've tried finding a python file for the mysql.connector online to upload to the function with no luck.

```py
import mysql.connector

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="test.url.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
            user="root",
            passwd="password",
            database="test")

     mycursor = mydb.cursor()
     sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('test')"
     mycursor.execute(sql)

     mydb.commit()
     return {
        status: 'success'
     }
```

I would like to successfully execute the SQL command above to the remote RDS database. But I keep getting `"Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'mysql'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying a Python function to AWS Lambda, you need to [bundle your dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#python-package-dependencies) with your Python file(s).

> If your function depends on libraries other than the SDK for Python (Boto 3), install them to a local directory with pip, and include them in your deployment package.